# when I update Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 what will happen for my Modules?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, upgrade, drupal-8

Currently running the 7 versions of Drupal to my website and most of the modules are the same version but recently I noticed Drupal 8 series is available. If I upgrade the code to the latest version, what will happen on the modules?

Comment: You will have to upgrade your modules to their Drupal 8 version.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrading-from-drupal-6-or-7-to-drupal-8

Comment: D7 & D8 are really different , so all modules need to change their structure , @2pha have right

Comment: @Fky When I update it's changing automatically or we change manually.

Comment: @AhamedSuraif you need to change manually

Comment: @Fky Thanks for your support.